# Extract maps url from dynamic string on android

Tags: java, android

i have this string

```
lat:54.897601 lon:4.707973
speed:0.03
T:18/10/11 13:52
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=54.897601,4.707973&z=16
Pwr: ON Door: OFF ACC: OFF
```

I want extract http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=54.897601,4.707973&z=16 in a string.
the message is dynamic. the url can be anywhere in the message. How do I extract from http to "empty space" or "new line" that would be the end of the link? I have tried a lot around but I can not solve my problem. 
I'm work on Android
Thank you

EDIT 1:
Hi,
if I want extract url from this message?

```
    String text2 = "sensor alarm!\n" +
            "lat:52.897639\n" +
            "long:78.707985\n" +
            "speed:0.05 \n" +
            "T:18/10/11 15:51\n" +
            "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=52.897639,78.707985&z=16";
```

\n doesn't work

EDIT 2:
If i want extract latitude and longitude for this string?

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=89.930893,75.721755&z=16
```

I want to point out that latitude and longitude will never be static. it will also be

```
 http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=9.993,7.725&z=16
```

I want this in String lat and String lon; 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String text = "lat:54.897601 lon:4.707973\n" +
            "speed:0.03\n" +
            "T:18/10/11 13:52\n" +
            "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=54.897601,4.707973&z=16\n" +
            "Pwr: ON Door: OFF ACC: OFF";

    String urlStr = text.substring(text.indexOf("http://maps.google.com"), text.indexOf("\n", text.indexOf("http://maps.google.com")) != -1 ? text.indexOf("\n", text.indexOf("http://maps.google.com")) : text.length());
    System.out.println(urlStr);
```

Comment: Thank you!! you are the best

Comment: Hi. i have editedt my question. Can you help me at Edit 1?

Comment: Ok! In this case need to check of index "\n" after "http". If index == -1 (no "\n" after "http") then index of the last char of url = text.lenght(). See answer updating.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, it work. I edited my question. Can you help me in EDIT 2? Thank you so much. You are the best